# Undocumented parameters in Firebase Dynamic Links REST API

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently using the https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest to build short dynamic links from both long links and parameters.

Missing from this documentation is feature parity that exists on console, like attaching a custom suffix to your short url.

I have already discovered undocumented functionality, like the missing ofl fallback parameter as the following.

```
{
  desktopInfo: 
  {
   desktopFallbackLink: "https://getspar.com"
  }
}
```

After doing some digging i've found some references to a suffix option `CUSTOM` that is missing from the canonical resources.

```
"suffix": { # Short Dynamic Link suffix. # Short Dynamic Link suffix. Optional.
      "option": "A String", # Suffix option.
      "customSuffix": "A String", # Only applies to Option.CUSTOM.
    },
```

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/firebasedynamiclinks/v1/python/latest/firebasedynamiclinks_v1.shortLinks.html

Also a mention of this in go autodocumentation as well https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/firebasedynamiclinks/v1#Suffix

However i'm getting

> Unsupported Suffix option CUSTOM

My guess is it is in fact exposed, I just don't know the correct data structure. Anyone

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I has been looking for the ofl parameter for a long time now :)

Comment: Also via the console you can assign a name, cannot find a way to assign a name when the link is created via the REST API :c

Comment: If someones find post in '21 this should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381474/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-short-link-with-firebase-dynamic-links/70338441#70338441

Answer (score 0):

As I encounter this issue, I just find out that **this feature is not available by using the REST API**. 
Right now it is only working for the links created by the Firebase Console.
That's why I think it is undocumented in REST API.