# Is it possible to specify the short link with Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

This question is about what I think is a discrepancy between the REST API (from the docs anyway), and the behaviour afforded through the Firebase console.

Here's the console:

[image]
[image]

Yet when I look at the [REST API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener), I don't see any way to follow step (1) from the Firebase console. I don't see any way to set up a short URL link, rather it looks like it will be generated. This is a shame because I wanted to generate guessable links. For reference, here is their specification sans platform-specific info keys (eg "iosInfo"):

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": string,
    "link": string,
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT" or "UNGUESSABLE"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to copy the console behaviour through the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to create persisting link in firebase dynamic link using API in node. I did the following.

1. Create oauth2 client

```
import {google} from "googleapis";

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "path to service account json file",
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase']
})
```

2. Create link data object

```
    const data = {
        "dynamicLinkInfo": {
            "domainUriPrefix": "https://myapp.page.link",
            "link": "my deeplink",
            "androidInfo": {
                "androidFallbackLink": "",
                "androidLink": "",
                "androidMinPackageVersionCode": "",
                "androidPackageName": bundleName // android package name, fe my.app.io
            },
            "iosInfo": {
                "iosAppStoreId": `${isi}`, // app store app id
                "iosBundleId": bundleName, // ios app bundle id, fe my.app.io
                "iosCustomScheme": "",
                "iosFallbackLink": "",
                "iosIpadBundleId": "",
                "iosIpadFallbackLink": ""
            },
            "navigationInfo": {
                "enableForcedRedirect": false
            },
            "analyticsInfo": {
                "googlePlayAnalytics": {
                    "utmCampaign": "",
                    "utmMedium": "",
                    "utmSource": ""
                },
                "itunesConnectAnalytics": {
                    "at": "",
                    "ct": "",
                    "mt": "",
                    "pt": ""
                }
            },

            "socialMetaTagInfo": {
                "socialDescription": "",
                "socialImageLink": "",
                "socialTitle": ""
            },
        },
        "name": "Link name column from FDL",
        "suffix": {
            "customSuffix": "URL_prefix_during_link_creation_from_FDL, "option": "CUSTOM"
        }
    }
```

3. Call the API

```
oauth2Client.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/managedShortLinks:create",
        data: data
    })
```

Links:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis
- https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/44.0.0/firebasedynamiclinks/interfaces/Schema$CreateManagedShortLinkRequest.html
- https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/44.0.0/firebasedynamiclinks/classes/Resource$Managedshortlinks.html#source

As far as I know, you cannot use any direct REST API since you need appropriate oauth2 access_token for specific scope. I was trying to spoof FDL requests and reflect it behaviour without success, but this works.

Comment: Now this is _very_ interesting. The `CUSTOM` option is not documented everywhere, but it _is_ documented in the [Node.js API you linked](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/44.0.0/firebasedynamiclinks/classes/Resource$Managedshortlinks.html#source) and looks exactly like what I was looking for.

Comment: But you cannot use API from FDL rest API doc because it says custom suffix is not supported. There is some mess around it.

Comment: For anyone wondering, if you put the above solution in Firebase Functions, you don't need to specify the service account `keyFile`. The only other difference is the way you import googleapis: `const {google} = require('googleapis');`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set custom suffix for short links created through API. If you have more details for your use case, I suggest filing it as a feature request https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set custom suffixes for short links created. We call it Managed Short Links.

Use the approach suggested by lisek, and for understanding here are the links to the latest docs from google dev.

1. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/firebasedynamiclinks/interfaces/Schema$CreateManagedShortLinkRequest.html
2. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/firebasedynamiclinks/classes/Resource$Managedshortlinks.html#source

Comment: Can you share why we cannot achieve the same functionality in iOS or Android SDKs?